# Minecraft Optimisation

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Having played minecraft on both my gaming PC and on my Netbook, i have experienced the 4 frames per second gameplay that minecraft has to offer for low end spec computers.

Besides from:

- Minimal settings
- low res texture packs (8x8 (may not help) )
- Optifine (fantastic!)
- Running less proccesses in background

Are there any other **significant or insignificant** ways to increase performance / reduce system dependancies.

Im hoping in the end (with multiple answers probably), to have a comrehensive list of performance boosts

Comment: I don't think the low res texture packs do anything, aren't most (if not all) of them just 16x16 packs where every "pixel" is really a 2x2 block of pixels?

Comment: Good point, im not sure of the facts but that may be the case

Comment: That used to be the case. Since 1.6 changed its texture setup to individual files, that might not be the case anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Put the world on an external server to offload most of the CPU and disk bound activity to the server and let the client just worry about displaying the world.

Comment: that would require an extra pc, unless you wish to run the server on the same machine, in which case the performance would actually suffer a loss (source: experience)

Comment: or you can use a (cheap) hosting solution, though most will be more expensive in the long run than a computer upgrade

Comment: some nice suggestions :) +1

Comment: Be aware that Minecraft's single player is really a hidden server running along with the client. This is why it's so easy to set your single player game visible to others. It just turns off the tiny firewall inside.

Comment: @VincentVancalbergh yes, and minecraft is already optimised to do so.. the answer is hosting a server. I own a server, and know that running minecraft on the same machine that is handling the server requires significantly more resourses

Comment: @DCA- well, then my work here is done :)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is not much to do with this config, maybe playing on a server to relieve the CPU... But it won't help much.

You can try these solutions: Update the drivers, remove the programs in the background, install a lighter system (Like Lubuntu, older windows ...)